# Codeigniter: Pass variable to the View

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have to table article and table comment. In the home page I want to see how many comment for earch article.

Model

```
function show_latest_article($start,$display,$cate)
{
    $query=  $this->db->get_where('news_news', array('News_Cate_ID'=>$cate),$start,$display);
    if($cate==0)
    {
         $query=  $this->db->get_where('news_news',$start,$display);
    }

    return $query->result();
}
     function count_comment($id)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('comment',array('comment_article_id'=>$id) );

         return $query->num_rows();   

    }
```

Controller

```
 function index() {
        $this->load->model('article');
        $data=array('article'=>$this->article->show_latest_article(0,8,1),
                    'sidebar'=>$this->article->side_bar(9),
                    'count_comment'=> $this->article->count_comment($id),

            ); 

        $this->load->view('page/index',$data);

    }
```

In the view I have this

```
    foreach($article as $art)
{
    echo $art->title."<br>";
    $id= $art->id;
    // I want to echo number of comment here.
   // Or I want to call function count_comment($id) 
}
```

Comment: So did you find the solution ?

Comment: I think I will try to join two table instead of call another query in the loop.

Comment: That can be a quick solution but please consider my solution too ... I'm keen to know if that worked well for you . At least for that I took the time to write it down for you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not so clear, where the `$id` variable come from, but I suggest to join the comments table to your article. It's not a best practice to make queries within loops.

In your model:

```
public function show_latest_article($ids = array())
{
    return $this->db
        ->select('articles.*, COUNT(comments.id) as comment_count')
        ->where_in('articles.id', $ids) // You can skip this
        ->join('comments', 'comments.article_id = articles.id', 'left') 
        ->group_by('articles.id')
        ->get('articles')
        ->result();
}
```

In your controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $data['articles'] = $this->article->show_latest_article(array(0, 8, 1));
    $this->load->view('page/index', $data);
}
```

Just change the field name according to database columns. Also you can skip the `where_in` condition. (I'm not sure what the three number stands for).

Then in your view, you can simply access the field:
`$art->comment_count`

*EDIT: According to your comment:*

```
$this->db
    ->select('a.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comment c WHERE c.comment_article_id = a.News_News_ID ) as counta')
    ->get('news_news')
    ->result();
```

Comment: Your solution look nice on 1 article but I want to get all article and it number of comment. My id is not article id not category id.

Comment: My bad, forget the to `left` join, I have updated the answer! You have to set left join, because articles which doesn't have comments won't appear.

Comment: This code work for me. Can u help me transfer it to codeigniter style.
SELECT a.*, ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comment c WHERE c.comment_article_id = a.`News_News_ID` ) as counta FROM `news_news` a

Comment: It's simple, added to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $this->load->model('article');
    $data['article'] = $this->article->show_latest_article(0, 8, 1);
    $data['sidebar'] => $this->article->side_bar(9);
    $data['count_comment'] => $this->article->count_comment($id);
    $this->load->view('page/index', $data);
```

And it should work.

Comment: can you please tell me what is the difference between your code and her code?

Comment: your solution isnt complete

Comment: $data['count_comment'] must contain an array of comments count because count_comment function returns only one comment count

Answer (score 0):

Controller :

```
 function index() {
    $this->load->model('article');
    $articles =  $this->article->show_latest_article(0,8,1);
    $count_comments = Array();
    for($i=0;$i<count($articles);$i++){
        $count_comments[$i] = $this->article->count_comment($articles->$id);
    } 
    $count_comments = 
    $data=array('article'=>$articles,
                'sidebar'=>$this->article->side_bar(9),
                'count_comment'=> $count_comments); 

    $this->load->view('page/index',$data);

 }
```

In the View :

```
$i=0;
foreach($article as $art)
{

    echo $art->title."<br>";
    $id= $art->id;
    echo $count_comment[$i]; 
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Use $i++ not work, cause the article id is not 1 to 100 sometimes I delete an article then it may mess up.

Comment: $i++ not work really ? LOOL ... You should have find a better reason cause ++ is one of the basic operators of Code Igniter.

Comment: People like you give me reason to post and share here knowledge ... Because you reaally need it ... Have a nice day sweety

Answer (score 0):

First of all in your controller you get count_comment only for specific article ID and not for all articles so you cant do foreach to display comment count of each article.

You need to setup you model better and in model function show_latest_article to use JOIN comments table and do count comment in query.

I will help you with query if you provide me more info about database table of article and comments.

```
SELECT 
    article.*,
    COUNT(comment.id),0) AS numberOfCommments

FROM article
LEFT JOIN comment
ON comment.article_id = article.id

GROUP BY article.id
```

Comment: article (
id, title,  body,   user_id)

comment(
id, article_id, user_id,    body)

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this answer as you provided code. It could be more simpler if you give more database details. Try below code

```
function index() {
    $this->load->model('article');
    $articles = $this->article->show_latest_article(0,8,1);

    foreach($articles as $article)
    {
        $article->comment_count = $this->article->count_comment($article->id);
        $all_article[] = $article;
     }

     $data=array('article'=>$all_article,
                'sidebar'=>$this->article->side_bar(9)
        ); 

    $this->load->view('page/index',$data);

}
```

**On view**

```
foreach($article as $art)
{
    echo $art->title."<br>";
    $id= $art->id;
    echo $art->comment_count;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Data is passed from the controller to the view by way of an array or an object in the second parameter of the view loading function. Here is an example using an array:

```
$data = array(
           'title' => 'My Title',
           'heading' => 'My Heading',
           'message' => 'My Message'
      );
$this->load->view('blogview', $data);
```

Also below is the example for object

```
$data = new Someclass();
$this->load->view('blogview', $data);
```

PLEASE NOTE: Note: If you use an object, the class variables will be turned into array elements.
You can find out more from below ref URL

Ref: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html